# Create HTML Passcode screen for web app

Tags: ios, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am working on a mobile webapp developed using jQuery mobile and I'd like to have a simple passcode lock screen that is similar to the iPhone general passcode screen.

The main problem I'm having is in getting the the numeric keyboard to show and only display a dot when the code is entered into each text box. At present the only way I can make it work across ios and android is to set the text field as type number, but then the numbers are displayed during passcode entry.

I was hoping somebody had done it already or had a simple solution.

Comment: Your best bet will probably involve different code for iOS and Android.

Comment: I was able to recreate what I needed by adding a simple keypad then adding some code in the pageinit event to update the display div and submit to the server after the requisite number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the use of such a passcode screen especially as a web app. But anyway you could do something hacky like this,

1. Create an input box with `type=number`
2. Create a jquery event onkeyup,

   - get the value entered in to a variable.
   - replace the content of the input box by `*`
3. When the OK button is pressed, check the value that is stored in the variable.

This way you get to use the Number-pad and not display the contents.